# Whats wrong with my makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
#####################################################################
# This is the filesystem makefile "make_BuddyAlloc".
# Author:Michael Gomes
# Date:2 jan 2011
######################################################################

#variable defination
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2
SRC_DIR=src
INC_DIR=inc
OBJ_DIR=obj

#List of source files 
SOURCE= buddyMain.c \
  Copy.c \


#List of object files 
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(SOURCE:.c=.o))

#BuddyAlloc is dependent on "obj/*.o".
BuddyAlloc : $(OBJECTS)
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o BuddyAlloc $<

#obj/*.o depends on src/*.c and inc/*.h, we are redirecting the object files to obj folder
$(OBJECTS):$(SRC_DIR)/$(SOURCE)  
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS) -c $<


#Cleans all the *.exe files
clean:
 rm -f *.exe
```

I have kept the source files under src folder includes under inc folder and the object files are being saved in obj folder .given above is the makefile i am trying to create for my mini project.
I keep getting the error no rule to make target 'Copy.c' needed by 'obj/buddyAlloc.o', but it works fine it i dont include Copy.c, what did i do wrong?

Comment: Beware trailing backslashes like the one after Copy.c in the SOURCE list.  In this case, you are OK, but generally, avoid leaving lists terminated with a backslash.

Answer (score 4):

This line is your problem: `$(OBJECTS):$(SRC_DIR)/$(SOURCE)`. The resulting string for the dependency (the right side of the colon) is `src/buddyMain.c Copy.c`. In other words, you are trying to prepend the source directory but it's only getting prepended to the first file.

There are numerous ways to fix this:

1. The manual approach:

   `SOURCE = $(SRC_DIR)/buddyMain.c $(SRC_DIR)/Copy.c`
2. `VPATH`, which adds directories to every search path (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search)

   `VPATH = src`
3. Or, as used in the Makefile already,
   use `addprefix` to introduce a new variable
   built from `SOURCE`:

   `SRCS = $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/,$(SOURCE))`

Comment: Correct diagnosis, but what's the recommended remedy?

Comment: His command shouldn't be using `-o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)`, given that `$(OBJECTS)` has had the directory added with `$(addprefix`. Also, I'm pretty sure the C compiler can't spit out all the objects like that. Why not just use a pattern rule?

Comment: @user577220 - remember to mark this correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using GNUisms in your `Makefile` anyway, so why not just use a pattern rule?

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<
```